Firebase Unity current user email doesn't update
I started using the new flow which has Email enumeration protection. For some reason after I send an email verification and the user follows the link in the email their email does not change. I trigger a ReloadAsync on the CurrentUser.Email and I expect that it should refresh the property to the new email, which was just verified by the user. Am I supposed to log out the user after they update their email, or am I missing something else? I am using firebase 12.2 for Unity
if (firebaseManager.Auth.CurrentUser != null)
{
    try
    {
        Credential credential = EmailAuthProvider.GetCredential(firebaseManager.Auth.CurrentUser.Email, password);
        await firebaseManager.Auth.CurrentUser.ReauthenticateAsync(credential);
        await firebaseManager.Auth.CurrentUser.SendEmailVerificationBeforeUpdatingEmailAsync(newEmail);
        return true;
    }
    catch (AggregateException aex)
    { ... }
}

Above is how I update the email. Below is how I refresh the form (no difference if I open/close the gameObject with the form).
void Start()
{
    FirebaseManager firebaseManager = FirebaseManager.Instance;
    Firebase.Auth.FirebaseUser currentUser = firebaseManager.Auth.CurrentUser;
    currentUser?.ReloadAsync().ContinueWithOnMainThread(task =>
        {
            if (task.IsCompletedSuccessfully)
            {
                currentEmailPlain = currentUser.Email;
                if (currentUser == null) EventsManager.Instance.AuthLogout();
                else CurrentEmail.text = Helpers.MaskEmail(currentEmailPlain);
            }
        });
}


What does open/close the gameObject mean? If Start is only called once and the CurrentEmail.text never assigned in a different place .. well then that's the issue

Seconding what @derHugo said and adding that Start() is only ever called once while OnEnable() is called whenever the object is enabled whether thats the first or nth time. OnEnable() is likely a better fit for trying to activate something with open-close logic.
